# How Do I Bind Data To Anchor Tag Query String In React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.

Here's what I'm trying...

```
<a href={'/ViewOpportunity?OpportunityId=' + opportunity.opportunityId.toString()}'>Learn More</a>
```

...where this binding works...

```
 <div className="col-md-12">
     <br />{opportunity.description.toString()}
 </div>
```

What's the proper way to add a query sting value in React?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a *proper* way of making a query string in react, but I typically use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to make any query string that I need as it will automatically encode and make the structure of it for me and it's built into the browser.

```
let query = new URLSearchParams({OpportunityId:opportunity.opportunityId}).toString();


<a href={`/ViewOpportunity?${query}`>Learn More</a>
```

I'm not sure what the variable type of opportunityId is, but this would usually work for me. Although if it's something like an object, you'll likely have to use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: How would this work if I’m binding to a collection? I’m not sure I can new up a javascript instance in the process.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are asking for in the question?